# SonataAdminBundle with Symfony ~2.4 - how to install?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

I just set up a new Symfony 2.4 project and try to install the SonataAdminBundle ([instruction](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html)), but I get errors again.

**History**:

```
# install symfony (demo works!)
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ./ 2.4.*

# install admin bundle (instruction above)
composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle
-> version: dev-master

# install DoctrineORMAdminBundle (FAILS!)
composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
-> version: dev-master
```

Well, I failed on [step 1.2](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html#selecting-and-downloading-a-storage-bundle), **error**:

```
Please provide a version constraint for the sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle requirement: dev-master
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file

  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
  The service "sonata.admin.builder.orm_datagrid" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.admin.builder.filter.factory".

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Interesting line:

```
The service "sonata.admin.builder.orm_datagrid" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.admin.builder.filter.factory".
```

Does anyone know what to do? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is going wrong? Please show us some errors...

Comment: Whats wrong with the documentation's composer? At least try to use that one and then show us the errors you get instead of just showing us a clean composer.json and AppKernel.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to register both the SonataAdminBundle and SonataDoctrineOrmAdminBundle. It looks like you forgot to activate SonataAdminBundle.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I had to do the steps 1.3 and 1.4 before trying to install the SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle.